# How to give the carousel image the full screen width?

Tags: flutter, carousel

I am learning about carousel in flutter. I want to give the carousel image the full screen width. But the width is automatically taken by the carousel itself. Is there any way  to give the image the full screen width inside carousel?
Here I have used both carousel_pro and carousel_slider, neither works as I expected. Please help.

```
  List _images = [
    Image.network(
        "https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/630x420/Lamborghini/Lamborghini-Huracan-EVO/6731/1546932239757/front-left-side-47.jpg?tr=w-456,e-sharpen"),
    Image.network(
        "https://auto.ndtvimg.com/car-images/big/lamborghini/aventador/lamborghini-aventador.jpg?v=5"),
    Image.network(
        "https://www.lamborghini.com/sites/it-en/files/DAM/lamborghini/gateway-family/few-off/sian/car_sian.png"),
    Image.network(
        "https://www.topgear.com/sites/default/files/styles/16x9_1280w/public/images/news-article/2018/01/38eba6282581b285055465bd651a2a32/2bc8e460427441.5a4cdc300deb9.jpg?itok=emRGRkaa"),
    Image.network(
        "https://blog.dupontregistry.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/lamborghini-egoista.jpg"),
  ];

  List _images2 = [
    "https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/630x420/Lamborghini/Lamborghini-Huracan-EVO/6731/1546932239757/front-left-side-47.jpg?tr=w-456,e-sharpen",
    "https://auto.ndtvimg.com/car-images/big/lamborghini/aventador/lamborghini-aventador.jpg?v=5",
    "https://www.lamborghini.com/sites/it-en/files/DAM/lamborghini/gateway-family/few-off/sian/car_sian.png",
    "https://www.topgear.com/sites/default/files/styles/16x9_1280w/public/images/news-article/2018/01/38eba6282581b285055465bd651a2a32/2bc8e460427441.5a4cdc300deb9.jpg?itok=emRGRkaa",
    "https://blog.dupontregistry.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/lamborghini-egoista.jpg",
  ];



            Carousel(
                images: _images,
                autoplay: true,
                boxFit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
                dotSize: 3,
                dotColor: Colors.red,
                dotIncreasedColor: Colors.red,
                autoplayDuration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            CarouselSlider(
              items: _images2
                  .map(
                    (x) => Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(x, scale: 1),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
              autoPlay: true,
              height: 200.0,
            ),
```

Comment: try BoxFit.fill instead of   BoxFit.fitWidth

Comment: What about Carousel_Slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is example, hope it works for you

```
 List<String> imgList;

     CarouselSlider(
                        items: map<Widget>(
                          imgList,
                          (index, i) {                    
                     return Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              child: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                                child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                                  InkResponse(
                                      child: Image.network(i,
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000.0),
                                      onTap: //....
```

Answer (score 54):

```
CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(
            viewportFraction: 1,
```

Comment: the viewport Fraction is used to set the width of the carousel Slider if its 1 then it will use 100% of the screen but by default its 80%.

Comment: worked for my carousel!!

Comment: Thank you Pang, Arshneet Kathuria...! Woking for me..!

Answer (score 1):

this simple example from me

```
CarouselSlider(
          items: _products
              .map(
                (p) => Image.network(
                  p.foto,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
          options: CarouselOptions(
            viewportFraction: 1.0,
            enlargeCenterPage: false,
            initialPage: 0,
            onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
              setState(() {
                currentIndex = index;
                _product = _products[index];
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

use  padEnds Property of CarouselSlider,

also assign full width for image

```
CarouselSlider(
          items: photoList
              .map(
                (e) => SizedBox(
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  child: Image.network(
                    e,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  ),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
          options: CarouselOptions(
            autoPlay: false,
            initialPage: 0,
            enableInfiniteScroll: false,
            padEnds: false, // take full width, remove padding from all size
          ),
        )
```